# Ubuntu 13.04 compizconfig problems

Tags: 13.04, compiz

I've just upgraded to 13.04 and when I open compizconfig the screen turns black for about 10 seconds and then it comes back but there is nothing besides the desktop and the program, the panel and window borders disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type:

ccsm

the output must be:

```
ccsm
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : gsettings
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : unity
Loading icons...
```

2 windows are open, the small one saying: 
**CSSM is an advanced tool. Use with caution.**
The big one is the **Configuration manager**.

Please feedback with your results, and maybe there is something relevant (by date) at your /var/crash path